# Add a link to onClick of a react component

Tags: reactjs

I want to add onClick event to my component that cause clicking that guide me to a new page by using Link to Router Elements.

I have tried bellow code:

```html
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
export default function NewsItemBox(props: NewsItemBoxOptions) {
  return (
    <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-6" onClick={()=>{<Link to="./"></Link>}}>
      <div className="single-blog-post">
        hello world   
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}`
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `history.push()`?

There is a `history` object in your `props` passed down by `Route`.

```
export default function NewsItemBox(props: NewsItemBoxOptions) {
const { history } = props; 
  return (
    <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-6" onClick={()=> history.push("/anotherpage")}>
      <div className="single-blog-post">
        hello world   
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}`
```

Comment: @alirezaasrari Like this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `history.push`, the `history`'s object is provided by your `Route` component, as in when you call `<Route render={props => <NewsItemBox {...props} />} />`, these props contain the `history`, which itself has useful functions that can help you.

Comment: how??!!
i want to add in my component that is placed in some part of my application and turn to another page

Answer (score 0):

This is how I manage to get `history` props in the nested component. So, I don't have to use any other dependencies to get the `history` object in the nested components.

**App.js**

```
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

 return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <div className="app ">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
```

**Home.js** Here you will get access to `history` props. So, pass it down to child component becasue child component doesn't have access to `history` props. What I have noticed is only the `Route` component has access to `history` props

```
 return (
  <div>
    <AnotherComponent history={this.props.history}/>
  </div>
);
```

**AnotherComponent.js**

```
return (
  <div>
  <div> <h4>hello dear world</h4> </div>

  {this.someLogic ? this.props.history.push("/new-page"): this.props.history.push("/amazing-page")}

  </div>
);
```